# java single package for whole module

Tags: java

We have muti-module gradle project, where we are planning to introduce parent level one package to reduce conflict with other module. Now this single package would have 200+ packages and 1000+ classes.

For example

```
Moduale1-|
         |
         |-src-|
               |-main-|
                      |-java-|
                             |-module1-|
                                       |-subpackage1
                                       |-subpackage2
                                       |-subpackage1
                                       ....
Module2-|
        ....
Module3-|
        ....
```

we are using JDK 8.

Does this architectural change is OK? Does it would have any issue in future like when it commes to JDK upgrade? or modular persective is this bad practice?

I'm not finding any limitation with single package with these manay subpackage and classes.

Comment: Avoiding split packages is a good idea. Split packages are packages that are spread out over multiple modules (i.e., you have the same package in more than one module) and this can cause problems.

Comment: In general no problem from JVM side. Probably Design Problem only, but this depends on the concrete project.